# Second Course in Algebraic Number Theory - Lang versus Neukirch

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, book-recommendation

So the title pretty much says it all. I have completed a first course in Algebraic Number Theory (number fields, ideal factorization in the ring of integers, finiteness of the ideal class group, Dirichlet's units theorem) and I now want to move on to a second course. The two books that have been suggested to me are Lang and Neukirch (both called Algebraic Number Theory). I would like to hear people's opinions and comments about how these two compare for a graduate-level reading course in ANT.

Many thanks!

Comment: Definitely go for Neukirch. IMHO Lang's books are great as a reference but not easy and pleasant to read and learn from.

Answer (score 0):

Neukirch is very complete and useful for future references, for example when you got into investigation. But it's a fat book.

Idk about Lang's book

Comment: By "investigation" do you perhaps mean "research"?